# How to list all images running in a cluster in CSV format?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to get a CSV for our security team with all the container images running in our kubernetes cluster right now including the image digests and namespace. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on anchore kai (which you just download and drop in your path. https://github.com/anchore/kai/releases) and jq which you probably already have installed. This also assumes your kubectl is configured and pointed to the cluster with needed credentials to read everything you need to acquire.

```
kai -i \
  |jq --raw-output '.results[] \
    | {"namespace": .namespace, "image": .images[].tag, "digest": .images[].repoDigest} \
    | [.namespace, .image, .digest] \
    | @csv' \
  `
```

The first line is getting the images using kai. The `-i` outputs the inventory to the commandline. This is in a json format. Then I use `jq` to get the results in line 2. In line 3 I re-arrange the results so the namespace is associated with each image in the same array. Then I dump these into a bunch of individual rows in line 4 and finally in line 5 output that to stdout in a CSV format instead of json.

You'll get a count of the images per namespace to stderr and the csv to stdout so you can simply add  `> inventory.csv` to the end of the command to save it off to a file. You'll still see the stderr output to the screen so you can follow along.